# passport-linkedin-oauth2 not returning email address

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, passport.js

Here is my console.log(profile);

```
{ provider: 'linkedin',
  id: 'LJitOAshpU',
  displayName: 'Monist BD',
  name: { familyName: 'BD', givenName: 'Monist' },
  emails: [ { value: undefined } ],
  _raw: '{\n  "firstName": "Monist",\n  "formattedName": "Monist BD",\n  "id": "
LJitOAshpU",\n  "lastName": "BD"\n}',
  _json:
   { firstName: 'Monist',
     formattedName: 'Monist BD',
     id: 'LJitOAshpU',
     lastName: 'BD' } }
```

here is my routing code:

```
 app.get('/auth/linkedin',passport.authenticate('linkedin', { scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile', 'rw_nus'],state: 'DCEEFWF45453sdffef424' }));

app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback',passport.authenticate('linkedin', { failureRedirect: '/' }),users.authCallback);
```

here is passport.js config:

```
 passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    clientID: config.linkedIn.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.linkedIn.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.linkedIn.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address','public-profile-url'],
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req,token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    console.log(profile);
}));
```

Why am I getting undefined in email values? It worked when I used passport-linkedin

Answer (score 2):

According to the [readme](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2), the `scope` option must be set in the `Strategy` object. You are setting it in `passport.authenticate` where it is being ignored.

To fix this change your code to:

```
app.get('/auth/linkedin',passport.authenticate('linkedin', { state: 'DCEEFWF45453sdffef424' }));

app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback',passport.authenticate('linkedin', { failureRedirect: '/' }),users.authCallback);
```

...

```
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    clientID: config.linkedIn.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.linkedIn.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.linkedIn.callbackURL,
    scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile', 'rw_nus'],
    profileFields: ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address','public-profile-url'],
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req,token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    console.log(profile);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give permission in your LinkedIn APP like below.

***IN this image you can see i have given many permission like in this emailaddress also check so i will get that***

[image: IN this image you can see i have given many permission like in this emailaddress also check so i will get that]